# Display element from array before looping

Tags: php, arrays

I need to display a certain `object` from an `array` before showing the rest of the `array`.

The array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [template_id] => 91
            [template_name] => Alphabet
            [template_thumbnail] => blank-template-thumbnail.jpg
            [template_create_date] => 1456821665
            [template_customer_id] => 0
            [template_is_responsive] => no
            [template_type] => builder
            [template_category] => simple
            [sort] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [template_id] => 92
            [template_name] => Blank Template
            [template_thumbnail] => blank-template-thumbnail.jpg
            [template_create_date] => 1456821670
            [template_customer_id] => 0
            [template_is_responsive] => no
            [template_type] => builder
            [template_category] => simple
            [sort] => 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [template_id] => 31
            [template_name] => Holiday Specials
            [template_thumbnail] => accommodation-1-20110926.jpg
            [template_create_date] => 1456821660
            [template_customer_id] => 0
            [template_is_responsive] => no
            [template_type] => builder
            [template_category] => Accommodation
            [sort] => 3
        )
)
```

I need to show `Blank Template` first and then show the rest alphabetically (the order it is in now.

Is there a more elegant solution than looping through the array twice? The size of the array can be anything from 1 (the blank template) to countless objects.

Comment: Isn't it better to use the template_id as index inside the array? Then you can give the blank template (by default) a id and call it by index.

Comment: When you loop the first time you can build a string by `$str .= (the rest in alpabetically order);` and once it finds "blank template" it echos it. Loop keeps building the string till end and echos it

Comment: Where does the output currently come from and how is it ordered there?

Comment: @Albert Do you need more help with this? Is none of the answers good enough?

Comment: @Andreas tried a few, decided to go with your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str="";
for($i=0;$i<=count($arr);$i++){
   if($arr[$i]['template_name'] == "Blank Template"){
         echo $arr[$i]['template_name'];
   }else{
         $str .= $arr[$i]['template_name']. "<br>";
   }
}

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$firstItem = null;
$outArray = [];
foreach($yourArray as $item){
    if($item->template_name == 'Blank Template'){
        $firstItem = $item;
    }else{
        $outArray[$item->template_name] = $item;
    }
}
ksort($outArray,SORT_STRING);
array_unshift($outArray,$firstItem);
```

Just one loop. Pay attention that this way of doing things, just work if you have uniqueness on the template_name!

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you, try

```
<?php 
$dataArray = array(0=>array('template_id'=>91,'template_name'=>'Alphabet'),
                   1=>array('template_id'=>92,'template_name'=>'Blank Template'),
                   2=>array('template_id'=>31,'template_name'=>'Holiday Specials')
                 );

$newArray = array();

foreach($dataArray as $key => $val)
{
    if(in_array('Blank Template',$val))///find the key for black template
    {
        unset($dataArray[$key]); ///unset black temp from original array
        $newArray[] = $val;///push black temp into new array at 0 index
        foreach($dataArray as $k => $v)
        {
            $newArray[] = $v; ///push the renaming values into new array 
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($newArray);

?>
```

This will give you :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [template_id] => 92
            [template_name] => Blank Template
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [template_id] => 91
            [template_name] => Alphabet
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [template_id] => 31
            [template_name] => Holiday Specials
        )

)
```

**LIVE EXAMPLE : [CLICK HERE](https://eval.in/576914)**